# Screenshot disappeared from question after edit, how to display it back?

Tags: support, screenshot

After I updated to add code samples, the screen shot disappered by magic!

I can see all the information required for SO to display it, but it did disappear anyway.

Here's the question where the screenshot disappeared by magic:

[**How to Moq this view?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669972/how-to-moq-this-view)

Following the image URL, it seems to have been blocked, why so suddenly?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxgMt.png

Is it just me due to the controlled environment, or has it really disappeared?

I just don't get it.

Anyone might explain to me?

Comment: You mean the single screenshot at the top of the post? I can see it just fine.

Comment: Really? Cool! This must be something with the controlled environment here, then. Thanks for having taken an eye out for me, @gunr2171!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After verification by @gunr2171, the image seems to display just fine outside of my environment.

It looks like the website where the image is stored has been blocked by the proxy on my side.

Thanks @gunr2171 for having taken an eye out!

Comment: Might be all those meme pictures your company does not want seeing. That's most of what is on imgur.